# Validation message not found

Tags: spring, validation, internationalization, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to implement a custom error message for my bean validation.
I've annotated my field `firstName` with the validation rule `@Size( min = 2, max = 40, message = "errors.firstName.size" )`.

In my `message.properties` I added a message key `errors.firstName.size=First Name must be between {min} and {max} chars`. However, in my Thymeleaf generated view just the message key appears (as the screenshot shows).

[image: Wrong message key]

Comment: Can you add the code for your thymeleaf HTML page ?

Comment: This is the part from the view `th:errors = "*{__${field}__}"`.

Comment: Not sure about this syntax. Did you try without preprocessing (e.g. `th:errors = "*{field}"`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your message key in `ValidationMessages.properties` instead of `message.properties`.

> The ValidationMessages resource bundle and the locale variants of this
>   resource bundle contain strings that override the default validation
>   messages. The ValidationMessages resource bundle is typically a
>   properties file, ValidationMessages.properties, in the default package
>   of an application.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkahi.html

Also, the validation annotation should be `@Size(min = 2, max = 40, message = "{errors.firstName.size}")`, [as heRoy said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28634756/178982).

Comment: That work's fine! Thank you! Only thing that bugs me is that the `ValidationMessages.properties` must be placed in the `resources` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add curly braces to your message key as below :

```
@Size(min = 2, max = 40, message = "{errors.firstName.size}")
```

Comment: Thank you! But that doesn't solve the problem :( `{errors.firstName.size}` is displayed in the view then..